# Any node.js relational database bindings for Windows?

Tags: database, windows, node.js

I'm trying to build a RESTful internal web server at work using node.js, where I'm currently restricted to using a Windows 2003 Server.

I've hit a stumbling block with regards to database support however. Are there any bindings currently available for reading and writing to sqlite, PostgreSQL or MySQL on Windows based machines?

Mariano has mentioned Windows support in the future in [these comments](http://nodejsdb.org/2011/06/node-db-drivers-update/#comment-24), but ideally I'd like to use something available just now as a proof of concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm author of [mysql-native](https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native).
Both official (felixge [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)) and my driver has been successfully used under windows,
I'm using and developing it under linux/windows 50/50% time . Feel free to contact me if you have any questions

Comment: Thanks - I've downloaded MySQL and initial tests with your driver seem fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mysql-native? It's native (mysql) which means there are no other dependencies, so should run on any platform node supports. Seems to be actively maintained also, and has some examples to show you how to use the library. Link: https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native